# Tile server technology for non-geographic data?

Tags: tile

Wondering if someone here can put me on the right path to finding research, algorithms or open source software for serving tiles that aren't geographic in nature. I suppose I'm also interested in client side software that exposes the titles to web users.

Everything I've found seems to be tightly coupled with mapping. However, it seems like there are other potential applications based on the same technology. For example, I have a huge photograph I want to break into tiles and allow for zooming and panning similar to Google Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want something that isn't geographic in nature? A tiled view is a tiled view.

A colleague of mine programmed [MagickTiler](http://code.google.com/p/magicktiler/), which basically works with every image. You can view the files using [OpenZoom](http://openzoom.org/) or other tile viewers.

> MagickTiler is a Java library and utility for converting image files into formats suitable for publishing them as high-resolution, zoomable Web images.
>
> MagickTiler also includes options for batch processing and quality control, supports a wide range of image input formats and the following output formats:
>
> - TMS tileset
> - Zoomify tileset
> - Google Maps tileset
> - Pyramid TIFF (PTIF)

Comment: "A tiled view is a tiled view." -- I would agree, but I get the impression just poking around that most implementations focus on map image sets. Maybe that's a misinterpretation and they will work with any image sets? 

From an architectural perspective, what are the major components in play? Sounds like I'd need a "tile viewer", a "tile server" and a "tile generator"?

Comment: Absolutely. In the case of the software I gave you, you create the tiles once using the "tile generator" and store them on a simple web server. They are viewed using a "tile viewer". The tile viewer will use a simple XML file to determine the dimensions and tile properties of the maps/images.

Answer (score 0):

Try these softwares to make the tiles on server side:

- GeoServer
- MapServer
- GeoMedia WebMap

Basically, these softwares get information from some database(including images) and build the tiles. To make the controls on client side like google maps you can use openlayers that is a javascript library.